# A tricky question regarding Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy-constructor

My confusion lies at line `Cube c = a;`. I think it should call both default constructor and copy constructor, but in fact it only calls copy constructor.
Isn't `Cube c`, just like `Cube a`, a new object that should invoke default constructor?

```
class Cube 
{ 
    public:
        int length_;

        Cube(){
            length_ = 1; 
            cout<< "Default Constr"<< endl; 
        }

        Cube(const Cube & obj){
            length_ = obj.length_;
            cout<< "Copy Constr"<< endl;
        }

}; 

Cube foo(){
    Cube c;
    return c; 
}

int main() { 
    Cube a; //invoke default constructor only
    Cube c = a; //invoke copy constructor only


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `Cube c = a;` is not _assignment_, but _initialization_. Namely, [_copy-initialization_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). "I think it should call both default constructor and copy constructor" — An object can be constructed only once, that is, only by one constructor call.

Comment: The syntax `Cube c = a;` means "copy-construct `c` from `a`"  (for the situation where `a` has type `Cube`, that is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, what you have here is copy initialization, so there's no way a default constructor would be used.

There is a slightly different case in which copy initialization can (at least theoretically) involve an extra step. Consider code like this:

```
class foo { 
public:
    foo(int) {}
};

int main() { 
    foo f = 1;
}
```

In this case, (at least before C++17) there were theoretically supposed to be two separate constructors involved. First, a temporary was constructed, initialized with `1`, then the copy constructor was called to initialize `f` from that temporary object.

In this case, most compilers will generate code that just directly initializes `f` from `q`, so it's equivalent to `foo f{1};`. The compiler is still required to respect the fact that a copy is needed though, so if you delete the copy constructor, compilation will fail:

```
class foo { 
    foo(foo const &)= delete;
public:
    foo(int) {}
};

int main() { 
    foo f = 1;
}
```

Result (with gcc):

```
trash9.cpp: In function 'int main()':
trash9.cpp:8:17: error: use of deleted function 'foo::foo(const foo&)'
         foo f = 1;
                 ^
trash9.cpp:2:9: note: declared here
         foo(foo const &) = delete;
         ^~~
trash9.cpp:4:9: note:   after user-defined conversion: 'foo::foo(int)'
         foo(int) {}
         ^~~
```

But changes in the rules starting with C++17 mean that now even that is allowed (so if I add `-std=c++17` to the compilation above, it succeeds).

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
Cube c = a;
```

This is actually not an assignment but a [*copy-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

In your case, it would be the same as if you had written:

```
Cube c(a);
```

Only the copy-constructor is called.

Keep in mind that an object is constructed only once, therefore only one constructor.

Answer (score -3):

The default constructor is called. 
It is used to initialize the object. 
Then the copy constructor is used to set the state of the new object to be the same with the initial one.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Only the copy-constructor is called. Why would the object be constructed twice ? You should read the comment from Daniel Langr

Comment: If you say 'The default constructor is called' for 'Cube c = a' it is not true.

Comment: That's simply not correct. Only 1 constructor is ever called for an object. Read up on copy-initialization, that's what is happening here.